# ARM STM32 need compatible compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, embedded, touch, arm

I am relatively new to programming with embedded hardware although not new to programming. I purchased the STM32F407VGT6 Multimedia Board, TFT LCD, SD, Accelerometer, USB from http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=5058&osCsid=9jkr9kor7d76qgvu76knsr0hp2. I thought I would be able to use the microC for ARM compiler but misread the demo version as 80 kb not actual amount of 8kb. To purchase this cost 300 and I really dont have the money for it. I have tried to find a different compiler that is compatible but so far have been  unable to.

I did find people mentioning that Code Sourcery lite might work although no one mentioned this specific board but the free version does not come already integrated with eclipse and I was unable to successfully integrate it.

I am really at a loss of what to do since I would rather not have to buy a whole new controller, and screen just to continue my project and I don't want to pay to purchase this compiler

If anyone knows a free IDE (even if its free for students only) that is compatible with this board it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search engine or link referral site. Google and Bing are both very good at searching and providing links to the results.

Comment: what is wrong with using gcc?

Comment: Specific issues encountered when integrating once of the gcc-codebase compilers (code sourcery lite, yagarto, etc) with eclipse would be very much on topic here, though the initial attempt should be made by researching existing information.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler is required only to support the instruction set of the processor. Board specific support itself is not the responsibility of the compiler.  Moreover in the case of ARM based devices, only the ARM core is the responsibility of the compiler; support for peripherals, and in particular the PLL clocking scheme for your part are also not the responsibility of the compiler.  So the fact that your board is not mentioned in the documentation is largely irrelevant.

Some tool-chains and particularly IDE's from the likes of Keil (an ARM subsidiary) and IAR provide a huge amount of chip and board support.  Both these companies provide demo versions, Keil's I believe is good for at least 32K, and the [IDE also supports free GNU tools such as Code Sourcery](http://www.keil.com/arm/gnu.asp), which has no restrictions on code size.

However in many cases and in particular the case of the STM32, a lot of the board support you need is available from the chip vendor.  ST provide a standard peripheral library and ARM CMSIS (ARM's standardised Cortex-M support API), plus many other libraries besides.  Keil actually ships ST's Standard Peripheral Library and CMSIS with its toolchain, but getting it form ST ensures the latest version.  The libraries and manuals can be found ion the Design Support tab [here](http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/product/252140.jsp).  The board page linked in your question has a link to download example code to support the off-chip board peripherals.

So the upshot is that Code Sourcery or other ARM GCC distribution will work fine, but you may need to build your complete development environment from parts such as chip or board vendor supplied libraries plus an IDE/debugger environment such as Eclipse or uVision.

With respect to using Eclipse, there is an article [here](https://sites.google.com/site/stm32discovery/open-source-development-with-the-stm32-discovery/setting-up-eclipse-for-stm32-discovery-development) describing how to do it for the STM32 Discovery board; most of which is applicable to your board at least for building if not for debugging/flash programming - the Discovery board has a built-in STLink JTAG debugger.

---

**Update June 2021**

A lot of the above is out-of date ST have largely deprecated support for the SPL and do not even provide it for newer series such as STM32F7, replacing it with he STM32Cube framework.

Importantly however ST now provide a free IDE with a toolchain and CubeMX integrated: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Yagarto?

http://www.yagarto.de/

It work on Windows and MacOS.

Or GNU ARM:

http://www.gnuarm.com/

Works primary on Linux and MacOS (also Windows through Cygwin).

Comment: These are just different distributions of the same codebase

Answer (score 1):

Add code sourcery lite to your path, so you can use it from command line, then install Eclipse with CDT. When installed create new cross compile executable project. Enter arm-none-eabi (verify that this is prefix of your toolchain) and you should be able to compile and debug your project.